# window server 2003 file sharing number of connection

Tags: windows-server-2003

Is there a limit on the number of concurrent users using a share folder ?

if yes how can i increase or decrease it ?

Answer (score 1):

From [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winservergen/thread/9a70af9e-c97f-4728-b195-e178a942450d):

> Based on the research, the
>   configuration of share folders is
>   stored in the following registry key
>   on the file server:
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Shares
>   To detect the maximum user connection
>   number, we can open the subkey which
>   names as the share folder’s name in
>   that node.   Technically speaking, we
>   may find the value of MaxUses, which
>   shows the maximum number that users
>   can connect to.

[image]

> However, the actual user's upper limit
>   of the concurrent connection number
>   depends on the CAL number that you
>   have.

So, theoretically, it's only limited by the number of CALS you've purchased.